# How to Perform the Network Service Discovery In Local Network?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking, udp

I have a server running on localhost with an Os assigned available port and now I have a client who wants to connect to the server but I don't know the IP address or whether this local network has a server.

Now I came to a solution that adds another UDP client and server first the UDP client sends a broadcast packet to the network and the UDP server will receive the broadcast packet now the UDP server knows the address and port of both the TCP server and UDP client address(from the broadcast packet) it will send the server address to UDP client then the UDP client gives it to TCP client for connection establishment.

But now the problem is First if we need to send a broadcast the UDP client and UDP server have to agree on the same port. Now how to choose this port, chosen port may be available on one machine but not available on another machine So choosing a static port between client and server is not the optimal way to do this task isn't it?

Now my task is to identify the server address and port, is using a static port on both the UDP client and the UDP server a good idea if not (mostly) how to achieve this task? I am using C++ with Qt framework Are there any tools or classes there for this kind of problem if not it is okay but at least I want to know how to solve this?

Comment: "with a random available port" - that's not how servers typically work.

Comment: I mean os will assign any available port, Thanks :)

Comment: There are established, standardized protocols for port discovery, such as UPnP. I think it would be more productive to invest a little bit of time learning how to use established, standardized protocols, that probably are already supported, out of the box, by your operating system, instead of trying to cook up a manual solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response I will look at UPnP, also I need a platform-independent Solution that will run on major platforms like Linux, windows, and Mac.

Comment: You will be happy to know that UPnP implementations exist on all major operating systems.

Comment: I searched for UPnP protocol, I can't find a good doc to use this protocol in C++ can you share any doc to learn this it would be very helpful.

Comment: There is also a possibility to use a broadcast message where a server announces on which ip addres/port it can be found by sending a packet with this information.  Look for UDP broadcast. Example here : https://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~dadi/compnet/labs/lab3/udp-broadcast.html

Comment: Thanks for your response In the example it uses an agreed port between the client and server but if I choose a static port like this may be available on one system by not on others.

Comment: If your server really is on localhost, you can just write a file which tells the port. Or, if you are launching subprocesses, command line argument or environment variable would work.

Comment: But the client is on different machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my observations, you don't have to use UDP broadcasting for device discovery. Since you're using the QT framework for your application, you can utilize the KDE API (KDNSSD), which does almost all the work for you. KDNSSD is a library for handling the DNS-based Service Discovery Protocol (DNS-SD), which is the layer of Zeroconf that enables network services, such as printers, to be discovered without any user intervention or centralized infrastructure. Please check the documentation here: https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kdnssd/html/

repo link : https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/kdnssd

Hope it helps